# SqlException generetad when i run my uwp Project

Tags: c#, uwp, code-first, sqlexception, ef-core-2.1

I have created a uwp project and a .NET Standard project.
.NETproject is the creator of my DB with codeFirst inside there are my model and my DBContext

My model

```
public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }

public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

DBContext and initialize method

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public EmployeeContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeeContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.Migrate();
        }
    }

public class Initialize
    {
        public static EmployeeContext GetContext()
        {
            var connectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=EFCoreTest;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            DbContextOptionsBuilder<EmployeeContext> options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EmployeeContext>();
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            return new EmployeeContext(options.Options);
        }
    }
```

In UWP (In app.xaml.cs) i call my DBContext to Create my DB at the first time but that's generated an SqlException

The call on my app.xaml.cs

```
var context = Initialize.GetContext();
```

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does `Initialize.GetContext()` do and to what database are you trying to connect? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i'm trying to connect on a local Db

Comment: Local DB? Given your connection string, it seems like you are trying to connect to a SQL Server but there is no one available at localhost. Did you install SQL Server on your computer?

Comment: but it works without uwp project and just a.NET Core app console

Comment: @mm8 I have an instance of Sql Server

Comment: Isn't localhost still blocked by default on UWP apps? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx#enable_loopback_for_network_access

Answer (score 0):

Your **ConnectionString** is not correct ,  Please check your **Connection** using visual studio

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My connectionString is right, i have an instance of Sql Server. I have already create Db on this server

Answer (score 0):

please check capabilities of your uwp application, if are activated .

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is @sayah imad